# Adding an element to an HashMap causes ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException in java 1.7.0_45

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

In my application, I've got some code that puts elements in an `HasSet` in the most classical fashion :

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@XmlElementWrapper
private Set<ParameterDefinition> parameterDefinitions = new HashSet<ParameterDefinition>();

// .... in a method far below ...
    this.parameterDefinitions.add(createParameterDefinitionFor);
```

This code has been in use for two years and has never shown any sign of failure.

however, we recently moved our codebase to java 7 (was high time). And, since that move, this precise instruction fails *only** on our Linux machine using Suse 10 and Java 1.7.0_45 witht the following stack trace.

```
  Daemon Thread [p: thread-pool-1; w: 9] (Suspended (exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException))   
        java.util.HashMap<K,V>.put(K, V) line: 498  
        java.util.HashSet<E>.add(E) line: 217
```

A test run on Windows with any Java 7 version doesn't exposes that behaviour.

So ... is there any reason this strange behaviour appear ?

Comment: Can we see the code where the map is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Glassfish? In that case the it is most likely this issue: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20814

Comment: Indeed, this bug happens in Glassfish.

Comment: This bug is fixed in Glassfish 4 I think, so upgrade to that if you're on a lower version. Your only other option is to use Java 1.7_25, but that might leave you at risk for security holes.

Comment: well, if I correctly understand the issue, I can also avoid those `HashMap` serializations by using only `@Local` EJBs, no ? Cause upgrading to Glassfish 4 just after upgrading to java 7 would be too much for our planning.

Comment: True! That's probably the safest solution.